# 2 dimensional array in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I can't seem to get the correct output on my 2 dimensional array.

The answer should be `1 5 9 2 6 10 3 7 11 4 8 12`
and I get `1 5 9 2 6 10 3 7 11`

The int intar line has to be that way.

Would appreciate any help!

Here is my code:

```
public class Assign8
{
    public static void main (String args[]){
    int intar[][] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};
    for (int i=0; i<intar.length; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<intar.length; j++)
            System.out.print(" " + intar[j][i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`intar.length` will be the number of elements in intar- in this case, the number of arrays, or the number of elements in the jth dimension. In the ith dimension, you need to iterate through intar[j].length, or the length of the jth array.

That's tough to do because you don't know what j is going to be at the time you're iterating through i. If you can assume that all of the "inner" arrays are the same length, you could do:

```
for (int i=0; i<intar[0].length; i++){ 
    // rest the same 
}
```

Comment: had to add int in front of (i=0;... ) and then it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for (int i = 0; i < intar.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < intar[i].length; j++)
            System.out.print(" " + intar[i][j]);
```

as an aside, it's better style to use the i index before the j (i does come before j)

Comment: agree about the style, but that won't give him the order he wants.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the length of the array is 3, you should change your code in this way

> for(int i=0; i < intar.length; i++) {
>           for (int j=0; j < intar[i].length; j++)
>               System.out.print(" " + intar[i][j]); }